# Reverse Axis in rCharts Without Sacrificing Animation?

Tags: r, d3.js, nvd3.js, rcharts

I have a dataframe of ranked values, in descending order. Naturally, when these are plotted along a Y-axis in rCharts, the low actual values (1,2,3...) are placed at the bottom of the axis and go up from there. Because I'm listing ranked values, I would like the sequence to be reversed: instead of going from low (bottom of axis) to high (top), I'd like it to progress from high (bottom of axis) to low (top).

I can accomplish this already using the following:

```
rankPlot$chart( yDomain = c(35,1) )
```

The problem is that this manually fixes the Y-axis values, which means that the axis will no longer dynamically adjust itself when certain values are removed or added as they do if the Y-axis is not fixed.

So the question is: is there a simple way to reverse the values on an axis that does not require manually fixing them?

**Update**: Here's the code I'm using to render the plot:

```
> rankPlot <- nPlot(
+     Rank ~ Date, 
+     data = lang.rank.hist.m, 
+     group = "Language",
+     type = "lineChart")
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the chart you are making. I believe I have a solution to your problem for several rCharts graphs, but the library includes many different types of graphs and I don't know which one you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want you need three steps:

1. Create an auxiliar variable with the negative value of the rank
2. Adapt your tooltip
3. Adapt the yAxis

The code below does those three things.

```
library(rCharts)

lang.rank.hist.m=data.frame(Date=rep(1:4,2),Rank=1:8,Language=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)))

# create an auxiliar variable with the inverse order
lang.rank.hist.m$neg.rank=-lang.rank.hist.m$Rank

rankPlot <- nPlot(
  neg.rank ~ Date, 
     group = "Language",
      data = lang.rank.hist.m, 
         type = "lineChart")

# rewrite the tooltip
rankPlot$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, val, e, graph){
return '<h3>' + '<font color=blue>'+ key +'</font>'+ '</h3>' + '<p>'+ val +
               '</p>' + '<p>'+  graph.point.Rank } !#")

# adapt the yaxis
rankPlot$yAxis(tickFormat = "#!function (x) {    
return -x}!#")
```